# PHPmailer - CC from dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmailer

New to PHP and have found myself building a custom contact form for a client.

I come from a Ruby background and fairly confident how I would approach this with e.g. the simple_form gem.

However, I'm stumped by this requirement from the client and must use PHP (WordPress site). When the form submits, he wants the email to go to him and then CC an email address from a dropdown, like so:

HTML pseudo-code:

```
<select>
    Manager A
    Manager B
    Manager C
</select>
```

I gather I need something like:

```
$mail->AddCC("ManagerA@company.com", "Manager A");
```

How would you populate that CC variable based on an HTML dropdown?

Comment: Is the select element part of the form ? Or do you have to select the cc option after the form is submitted. Either way you can get the value with `$_Post['select element name'] `

Comment: Yes, the select element is part of the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll find a lot of benefit from looking [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp). In Ruby the server spits back `params` which is an array of all the things that are usually needed from a request. In PHP it's all at a lower level of categorization. So on a `post_action_page.php` you'll end up utilizing the `$_POST` which is a globl array of data passed from the HTML form element. Then there is the `$_GET` a global array of variables passed in the URL string. Those make up the usual data you need from `params` in Ruby.